# How can we Delete a Folder along with app uninstallation in anroid?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to java programming in android studio. I am now creating an application which saves the user data as a text file in a specific folder.THe  problem is, when the user uninstalls the app ,the folder is not deleted and then, when the app is reinstalled, the data is restored. I don't want that to happen. How can we delete a specific folder or file during app unistallation in android java. My file location is :

```js
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/VCL/databases/";
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.Thanks in Advance

Comment: So don't use external storage for saving internal app data. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: `the folder is not deleted and then, when the app is reinstalled, the data is restored.` ?? If there is nothing deleted then what would be restored? Makes no sense.

Comment: The folder is not deleted along with the app uninstallation. So a file containing user credentials is existed on the external storage. So when app re-installs,it opens with the previous user credentials. My question is how can we delete a folder in  phone storage along with app uninstallation  using java in android studio

Comment: Do the file saved in the internal app data deletes along with app uninstallation

Comment: can we store large data in shared preferences